# SQL Stored Procedure Syntax error missing 'end'

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I've been working on an SQL stored procedure and am very new to the process. I'm trying to write a procedure that retrieves a value from one table and inserts it into another as part of a new row.

I'm using MySQL Workbench, and it's giving me an error at the line

```
WHERE blockId = blk;
```

As part of the following code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_userblock`(IN user INT(11), IN blk INT(11))
BEGIN
    -- Determine how many blocks you can add
    DECLARE blockNum INT DEFAULT -1;
    SELECT addCount INTO blockNum
        FROM block
        WHERE blockId = blk;

    -- Determine if the block already exists for the user
    DECLARE entryExists INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO entryExists
        FROM userblock
        WHERE blockId = blk AND userId = user;

    IF (entryExists = 0)
        -- This is a new entry
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO userblock (userId, blockId, num) VALUES (user, blk, blockNum);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as 'id';
        END
    ELSE
        -- This is an existing entry
        BEGIN
        UPDATE userblock
            SET num = (num + blockNum)
            WHERE userId = user AND blockId = blk;
        END
END
```

The error is "Syntax error: missing 'end'". I'm not entirely sure what it means, and I'm having trouble solving the issue.

Thanks, I appreciate your time!

Comment: You don't have an `END` on your `ELSE` block.

Comment: According to your indentation: _`IF (entryExists = 0)...`_ does not have a matching 'END'. late to the party again :)

Comment: Thanks for laying the code out so clearly - it makes maintenance a lot easier.

Comment: @Politank-Z are you sure the code is missing `END` on `'ELSE` block?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried to insert an END at the end of the IF ELSE block but can't fix the error. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Depends on your perspective. As Ryan Vincent points out, from his indentation, yes. As the interpreter would look at it, he is missing from the end of his procedure.

Comment: Move the 'declare blocks' to the top of the procedure. It compiles fine here. i.e. declare all the variables at the top of the procedure.

Comment: Moving the declare blocks to the top, as well as changing the syntax to MySQL-specific (IF ... THEN, ELSE, END IF) solved the problem for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer explaining what the issues were.  How they were solved. etc.You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help, I was able to solve the issue (at least as far as compiling goes) with the following code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_userblock`(IN user INT(11), IN blk INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE blockNum INT DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE entryExists INT DEFAULT 0;

    -- Determine how many blocks you can add
    SELECT addCount INTO blockNum
        FROM block
        WHERE blockId = blk;

    -- Determine if the block already exists for the user
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO entryExists
        FROM userblock
        WHERE blockId = blk AND userId = user;

    IF entryExists = 0
    THEN
        -- This is a new entry
        INSERT INTO userblock (userId, blockId, num) VALUES (user, blk, blockNum);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as 'id';
    ELSE
        -- This is an existing entry
        UPDATE userblock
            SET num = (num + blockNum)
            WHERE userId = user AND blockId = blk;
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as 'id';
    END IF;
END
```

The issue seemed to be a combination of two things:

1. I was using the wrong IF ELSE syntax for MySQL workbench's stored procedures
2. I needed to declare my variables at the top of the procedure

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

Add `END IF` after the `ELSE`-block

```
CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `add_userblock`(
  IN user INT(11), 
  IN blk INT(11)
)
BEGIN
-- Determine how many blocks you can add
DECLARE blockNum INT DEFAULT -1;
SELECT addCount INTO blockNum
  FROM block
 WHERE blockId = blk;

-- Determine if the block already exists for the user
DECLARE entryExists INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO entryExists
  FROM userblock
 WHERE blockId = blk
   AND userId = user;

IF (entryExists = 0)
    -- This is a new entry
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO userblock (userId, blockId, num) VALUES (user, blk, blockNum);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as 'id';
    END
ELSE
    -- This is an existing entry
    UPDATE userblock
       SET num = (num + blockNum)
     WHERE userId = user AND blockId = blk;
END IF
END
```